# Convert Blob to String in HQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, blob

I have a column typed BLOB in my Oracle DB, and I want to get a short overview as string (e.g limited to 300 char).

My column is annoted @Lob in Hibernate, my question is how can I convert my Blob (actually @Lob) to String ?

In my model:

```
@Lob
private byte[] content;
```

When I want to parse my blob I get:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
  Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: 
  JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [99999]; error code [24816]; ORA-24816: 
Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column; 
  nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: ORA-24816: 
Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column
```

I know that I can do a conversion in Java (`new String(myBlob);` for example), but I would like to get the string directly with my HQL query.

Comment: I think you can't do it directly from HQL. I always retrieve blob fields into `java.sql.Blob` type and then use adequately.

Comment: @malaguna thank you for your answer, I continue to search on the web but I think you're right.